# OnClick event in an image control not able to return value in a textbox control on the same form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. In a form, I used to have a command button control with VBA function in it. And one of the procedure is to read the value in a textbox in that same form. It works fine but when I tried to put an image control and put a procedure in its onclick event to read the value of the same textbox, it returns NULL. Am I missing a difference in terms of using the onclick event between a command button control and image control?

UPDATE:
Thanks @June7. Here's the file that I made that better shows the issue that I'm experiencing.

[ControlIssueACCDBFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yShEA4paTLFmHUNP3BhJAhFYlGCxNU4L/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks,
Darren

Comment: It works for me, no difference.

Comment: What version of MS Access are you using @June7? I am using the Office 365 (Version 1805 Build 9330.2087) I tried to investigate more by trying different actions. All confirm that I am having an issue. In VBA, it will be able to return the value of the textbox if it is put in a command button but returns NULL (depending on situation) if you put the same action in the onclick event of an image. I made a .accdb file to better describe the issue that I'm having but I do not know how to attach the file.

Comment: I use Access 2010. Cannot attach files in this forum. Would have to upload to a fileshare site such as Box.com and post link. Or go to a forum that allows attaching files.

Comment: @June7 I edited and attached a file that mimics the issue that I'm having and to clearly see what's happening. There's a clear description there on how to produce the issue.

Comment: If I enter or tab out of txtTextCopy, then click the image control, its code runs.

Comment: Yes I agree.  Where I'm actually using this method is on a logical statement that checks if the textbox IsNull. I used to have a button where the method was attached then I just decided to use an image instead and that's how I discovered the issue. It works fine if you use a button control but not with an image control. When the image control was click, the IsNull function returns TRUE and even Len(Me.txtTextCopy & "")=0 returns TRUE as well even if there's a value inside the textbox. What I actually did to make it work is to change .setfocus to other control which is not needed with a button

Comment: I was just hoping that it should work the same as using a button that there is no need to change focus (.setfocus) to verify if the textbox IsNull or Not IsNull.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. My original testing only read a value from a field of existing record on the click, not entry into an unbound textbox

Comment: You can also place a transparent button over the image to catch the click.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this issue which is actually not an issue according to the person that answered my question from another forum. It is not really the **OnClick()** events that are acting differently but the **behavior** of the control. So what's actually happening is that **not until the focus leaves the textbox**, it will always **return NULL even if there's a value**. A **Command Button can receive focus** but an **Image Control cannot**. That's why there is **no** any **focus related events property** to an **image control**. So when you click a **Command Button**, the **focus was transferred to the button** from the textxbox thus will return the **TRUE STATE** of the textbox. But if you click an **Image Control**, the **focus stays on the textbox** thus will a**lways return TRUE from an IsNull()** function. Having said this, to make this method work with an Image Control via VBA is to **transfer the focus** first to other control (.SetFocus) before testing if the textbox IsNull() or Not IsNull().